# moderncv linkedin symbol and greek language

Tags: babel, moderncv, greek, english

I am using babel in moderncv in order to switch between greek and english language with default language greek but i had an issue with social infos (such as email,webpage)i could not add them in english..

For example i was adding in the code :

`\homepage{www.example.gr}`

and i was getting in pdf :

[image]

so a user suggested me to add these lines in code (and that fixed the issue)

```
\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\homepagesymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
```

but now i have the same issue with linked symbol, I add this code :

```
\social[linkedin]{gr.linkedin.com/in/test}
```

and i get this :

[image]

I am posting here the first lines of my code :

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\cfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}

\makeatletter
% provide an expandable version of \roman
\newcommand{\exproman}[1]{\romannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% patch the commands in moderncv that use \roman
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\makeatother


% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
% if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{test}{test}
%\title{Biografik'o Shme'iwma}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{dress, city, postal}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{(+30) 325245345}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{(+30) 2352352}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\homepagesymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}

\email{test@gmail.com}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{http://gr.linkedin.com/in/test}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\social[linkedin]{gr.linkedin.com/in/test}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following line to your code (best after the `\xapptocmd` lines you already have):

```
\xapptocmd\linkedinsocialsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
```

Then your linkedin address will be in english.

Just for the case you add other things, that are the other defined symbols that can occur (copied from `moderncv.cls`):

```
\newcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\newcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {}
\newcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {}
\newcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {}
\newcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {}
\newcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {}
\newcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {}
\newcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {}
```

After the command `\newcommand*` you find the several names.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\cfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}

\makeatletter
% provide an expandable version of \roman
\newcommand{\exproman}[1]{\romannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% patch the commands in moderncv that use \roman
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\makeatother


% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}    

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{test}{test}
%\title{Biografik'o Shme'iwma}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{dress, city, postal}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{(+30) 325245345}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\homepagesymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\linkedinsocialsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}

\email{test@gmail.com}                        

\social[linkedin]{gr.linkedin.com/in/test}
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]